# Get Workrave to treat video watching as "work", not rest

Tags: 13.10, video, vlc, workrave

I use workrave not just to avoid RSI, but also as a tool to save my eyes.
I only have the rest break set up every 70 minutes.

The problem is that it treats events like video-watching as inactivity and resets, then stop the timer till I'm done watching the video, which can be hours if I'm watching something engrossing (I generally use VLC for playback).

The inactivity reset is great when I'm working, because it treats periods I spend away from my computer (walking around or answering a phone call) as breaks. The only qualm I have is with video playback being counted as idle time.

How do I solve this?
Suggestions for other software that meet my criteria are most welcome.
**Specifications:** Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, Workrave-1.10.1

Comment: I wonder what should you do when video is interrupted. You can easily stop reading and come back later but how do you come back to the video which runs away in real time?

Answer (score 5):

I think if you turn on "reading mode" in workrave, it will always count down the time, regardless of how much keyboard/mouse usage you do.

[Workrave documentation](https://workrave.org/docs/menus/reading-mode/) says:

> Workrave has a special mode for reading. While reading, you usually do not use the keyboard and mouse. Therefore, Workrave would normally not ask you to take breaks. When the reading mode is active, Workrave will also remind you to take breaks while reading.

> In reading mode, Workrave will start the break timers as soon as you start using keyboard or mouse. The timers will keep running until the first rest break, even if you stop using the keyboard and mouse. During this time you will be reminded to take microbreaks. After the first restbreak, the break timers stop until you start using keyboard and mouse again. Then it all starts over.

Comment: That is correct. I was wondering what does reading mode do